# What's the song playing when the group is discussing what to do while Bisky throws the dodgeball in episode 70?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

What is the song that is played in episode 70 while the group is discussing what to do and it continues while Bisky throws the dodgeball?

Comment: What was the exact minute?

Answer (score 0):

The scene you're talking about starts at 20:13

That song is one of my favorites, its name is : **Reason ~ Instrumental**

(Yeah it is the instrumental version of the ending 3)

Here is a link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7uXsgsZlps

(The part you're looking for starts at **1:05**)

It is also played when Kirua fights Rammot